# How does popa and pusha actually works?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, qemu

I am attempting to write a simple OS from scrath, but I have stumbled into a problem.
I wrote a simple procedure that runs through a string and prints it on the screen.

```
print_string:
    pusha
    cmp byte[bx], 0    
    je exit             
    mov ah, 0x0e        
    mov al, [bx]        
    int 0x10            
    inc bx              
    jmp print_string    
    
    exit: 
        mov ah, 0x0e       
        mov al, 13          
        int 0x10            
        mov al, 10          
        int 0x10            
        popa
        ret
```

And I am including it on the main file.

```
[org 0x7c00]              

mov bx, hello               
call print_string           
mov bx, hi                 
call print_string          
jmp $                       

%include "print_string.s"   
hello:                  
    db "Hello, World!",0     
hi:
    db "This is a test.",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0       
dw 0xaa55
```

But for some reason, instead of printing `Hello, World! This is a test.` it just prints `Hello World!`

When I remove the `pusha` and `popa` from print_string.s and place it on the main file like this:

```
[org 0x7c00]              

mov bx, hello    
 
pusha          
call print_string 
popa      
    
mov bx, hi   

pusha               
call print_string   
popa 
       
jmp $                       

%include "print_string.s"   
hello:                  
    db "Hello, World!",0     
hi:
    db "This is a test.",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0       
dw 0xaa55
```

It works just fine. Why?

Comment: As Maxim says, pushing & popping need to be *dynamically* balanced, not *statically* balanced.  Dynamic goes to runtime execution of the instructions whereas static goes to layout of the (source) code.

Comment: Because your `pusha` is in the loop body. Therefore it's getting executed each time you loop, where you only ever `popa` once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print_string` is called in the loop, on each iteration is does `pusha`. But there is only one `popa` instruction for multiple `pusha`.

Each `pusha` instruction adjusts the stack pointer down and a corresponding `popa` instruction adjusts the stack pointer back up. These instructions need to be *dynamically* balanced, as @ErikEidt accurately notes.

A fix (using `.label` for local labels):

```
print_string:
    pusha
.next_char:
    mov al, [bx]        
    test al, al
    jz .exit             
    mov ah, 0x0e        
    int 0x10            
    inc bx              
    jmp .next_char   
.exit: 
    ...
```